# Magento get URL before current

Tags: php, magento

I want to get URL before the current one in Magento and check if is shopping cart and checkout page. For example now I am in the My account page, I want to check if the visited page before My account was Shopping Cart page.

I try to add this function but is not work because my last URL is login, not 
shopping cart

```
   public function customerRegistration(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
       $lastUrl = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();
       if(preg_match("#onestepcheckout/index#", $lastUrl)){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
         }
         else{ 
           Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
   }
```

Update:

i find a solution, to redirect after register to checkout page if there exist a product in cart, but is a problem, after register is complete in the checkout the Billing fields is not complete and the user is not login. Anyone?

**New Update:**

This is what I made to redirect after login and it is work perfect, I need to do the same for Register. The problem with Register is because here the lastUrl is login. Anyone? with any idea?

```
  public function customerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {    
           if (Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isEnabled() && !Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getRedirectregister()){    
               $lasturl = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();
             if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') === false){
                 if (! preg_match("#customer/account/create#", $lasturl) && Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isoptionEnabled('login_customerredirect')) {
    if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCart() == 1 || Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCheckout() == 1){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
         }
    else
        {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
           Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
                }
            }
         }
        Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setRedirectregister(false);
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('0');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCheckout('0');
   }
```

**Update:**
A good developer told me that is a way to do this. To add an event before going to register page then add an event observer after registration is complete and then check what is necessary. But I don't know to do this, maybe someone can help me with this? Thank you
Thank you

My Original Code

```
  public function customerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {    
           if (Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isEnabled() && !Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getRedirectregister()){    
               $lasturl = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();
             if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') === false){
                 if (! preg_match("#customer/account/create#", $lasturl) && Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isoptionEnabled('login_customerredirect')) {
    if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCart() == 1 || Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCheckout() == 1){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
         }
    else
        {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
           Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
                }
            }
         }
        Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setRedirectregister(false);
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('0');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCheckout('0');
   }






   /*method for SignUp Customerredirect*/
  public function customerRegistration(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
    Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setRedirectregister(true);
        if (Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isEnabled() && Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isoptionEnabled('registration_customerredirect') ) {

               $_session = $this->_getSession();
               $_session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customerredirect')->setRedirectOnSignup());
        }
   }
```

This is my config.xml of this extension

```
<events>
    <customer_login>
        <observers>
            <customerredirect>
                <class>customerredirect/observer_customer</class>
                <method>customerLogin</method>
            </customerredirect>
        </observers>
    </customer_login>
    <customer_register_success>
        <observers>
          <customerredirect>
            <class>customerredirect/observer_customer</class>
            <method>customerRegistration</method>
          </customerredirect>
        </observers>
    </customer_register_success>
</events>
```

So all I want now is the Register page to work like Login, In present the login redirection is perfect, but for Register always I am redirect to My Account page. Not to the checkout page.

New Option:

```
if (strpos(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl(), 'checkout/cart') !== false) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('1');
} else {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('0');
}
if (strpos(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl(), 'onestepcheckout/index') !== false) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCheckout('1');
} else {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCheckout('0');
}
```

Comment: You can use cookies (both client and server side).

Comment: you know how to do this?

Comment: Client side: $.cookie(KEY,[VALUE]);

Comment: I understand but how we can use this in our code?

Comment: You might want to read after how cookies work, and from there it should be quite easy to implement it (given that you know php).

Comment: do you know something about add url's in array and compare them? I think is more interesting

Comment: please add here your idea, make your code to work in my code ...

Comment: so the idea is like that, we need to store last 3 urls and compare them, if one of the last 3 urls was checkout/cart then redirect to checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier solution.

Create an override of:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

Copy _loginPostRedirect() method

In the newly created file, in _loginPostRedirect method edit:

FROM:

```
$this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
```

TO:

```
    $sUrl = $session->getBeforeAuthUrl( TRUE );
    // Do url exclusions and conditional checks here

    // Force user to go home on login.
    $sUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl();

    $this->_redirectUrl( $sUrl );
```

Cleaned up with your conditionals (they are a bit convoluted):

```
    $sUrl = $session->getBeforeAuthUrl( TRUE );
    if (Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isEnabled() && !Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getRedirectregister())
    {    
        $lasturl = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();
        if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') === false)
        {
            if (! preg_match("#customer/account/create#", $lasturl) && Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isoptionEnabled('login_customerredirect')) 
            {
                if( Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCart() == 1 || Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCheckout() == 1 )
                {
                    $sUrl = Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index');
                }
                else
                {
                    $sUrl = Mage::getUrl('customer/account');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $this->_redirectUrl( $sUrl );
```

Edited for register:

```
$sUrl = $session->getBeforeAuthUrl( TRUE );
if (Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isEnabled() && !Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getRedirectregister())
{    
    if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') === false)
    {
        if ( Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isoptionEnabled('login_customerredirect')) 
        {
            $lasturl = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();
            if( Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCart() == 1 || Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCheckout() == 1
            || preg_match("#customer/account/create#", $lasturl) )
            {
                $sUrl = Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index');
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thank you for your answer, can you put here in your code my conditions? I am not very experimented developer, and I don't understand very well

Comment: or maybe if we can I think a good thing for me will be to have this work in that public function, is already created and for me now is work perfect on login

Comment: I added your conditionals - would recommend reading on controller overrides to avoid touch core code.

Comment: I understand I will try this right now, thank you very very much

Comment: this code must remain? $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));

Comment: anyway I think is the same problem like before, so when you press on Proceed to Checkout in the Shopping Cart page you are redirected to login page, and then for new user we need to press Register Button and another page will be open, so the last page is customer/login, so the Shopping Cart page is not the last url

Comment: Can you edit your original answer and add all the conditionals for new redirects that you would like? As in guest -> cart, guest-> checkout, user->cart, user->checkout, guest->login and what redirects they should all have?

Comment: please take a look at the very bottom

Comment: so my condition on the Register page must be, if the customer was in the Shopping Cart page then redirect him after register to checkout page, else to My Account

Comment: thank you so much, is still redirect me to the customer/account/

Comment: so I think the problem is here as I said, the Shopping cart page is not Lasturl , the Last url is the Login page, maybe for this your code is still redirect me to my account

Comment: You need to replicate the conditional for registration and add another one for login. When I registered with a shopping cart I was then redirected back to shopping cart.

Comment: I have conditions in the shopping cart  on that button, if the user is login the redirect to checkout, else redirect to Login page, and I can;t remove that, is need to be there

Comment: hmm and how we can do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105512/discussion-between-robertd-and-vladimir-ramik).

Comment: I test it again and again, all redirects are in the my account

Comment: Hi Vladimir, can you help me please with this redirect? can we solve this? thank you

Comment: Robert, you have custom modules in your code that you want to use with additional redirect logic. I would try to figure it out on your own using the examples I provided.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I disable that module for redirection, and leave there only your code in the controller, and it is the situation. I am still redirect to My Account, what I should do?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, can you take a look at the very bottom of my post, I add there New Option, I can use that in the register page to redirect on checkout page, for login is work perfect but for register is not work because the lastUrl is login not checkout/cart/ you have any idea, how I can solve this?