# Redirect after register to checkout issue - Magento

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I have a problem, I make a function to redirect my customers to checkout page after register if they have 1 product in cart. But after redirection the Billing Address in the checkout page is not populate with data and the user is not login.

this is my redirect function:

```
  $item = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
    if($item >0)
    {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }
```

**Original Code:**

```
  public function customerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {    
           if (Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isEnabled() && !Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getRedirectregister()){    
               $lasturl = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();
             if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') === false){
                 if (! preg_match("#customer/account/create#", $lasturl) && Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isoptionEnabled('login_customerredirect')) {
    if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCart() == 1 || Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCheckout() == 1){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
         }
    else
        {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
           Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
                }
            }
         }
        Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setRedirectregister(false);
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('0');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCheckout('0');
   }






   /*method for SignUp Customerredirect*/
  public function customerRegistration(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
    Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setRedirectregister(true);
        if (Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isEnabled() && Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isoptionEnabled('registration_customerredirect') ) {

               $_session = $this->_getSession();
               $_session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customerredirect')->setRedirectOnSignup());
        }
   }
```

**Updated Code:**

/app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc/config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Amit_Custommodule>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Amit_Custommodule>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <custommodule>
                    <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
                </custommodule>
            </models>
        </global>
        <frontend>
          <events>
              <customer_register_success>
            <observers>
              <notify_user>
                <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                <method>myredirection</method>
              </notify_user>
            </observers>
              </customer_register_success>     
            </events>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

/app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model/Observer.php

```
 <?php
    class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Observer {
        public function myredirection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $AccountController = $observer->getEvent()->getAccountController();

        $Customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

         $response1 = Mage::app()->getResponse(); // observers have event args

            $url = 'http://magento.edreamag.com/';
            $response1->setRedirect($url);
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->sendResponse();

        return;
      }
    }
```

/app/etc/modules/Amit_Custommodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/html/header.phtml

```
<?php
  $currentUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true));
if (strpos($currentUrl,'checkout/cart') == true || strpos($currentUrl,'onestepcheckout/index') == true) {
  $myValue ='yes'; 
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCurrpage($myValue);
} else {
  if (strpos($currentUrl,'customer/account/create') == true || strpos($currentUrl,'customer/account/create') == true) {
  }else {
  $myValue ='no'; 
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCurrpage($myValue); 
}}
?>
```

Comment: which file you are adding this code?

Comment: I have one extension for redirect

Comment: where is login code ?

Comment: I need this for new registered user, the login is work perfect, and the register is in the persistent folder. Please take a look here for more informations, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825317/magento-get-url-before-current

Comment: register is also from extension or using default magento?

Comment: is use the default magento register

Comment: pleaase take a look I edit my post and I add Original Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i prefer this solution for you

**Step1:**
create  `config.xml` is `app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc/` - See more at: http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/#sthash.JSktrUD0.dpuf
and it code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Amit_Custommodule>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Amit_Custommodule>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <custommodule>
                    <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
                </custommodule>
            </models>
        </global>
        <frontend>
          <events>
              <customer_register_success>
            <observers>
              <notify_user>
                <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                <method>myredirection</method>
              </notify_user>
            </observers>
              </customer_register_success>     
            </events>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

**Step2:**

create module control file Module name as  Amit_Custommodule.xml at app/etc/modules/

it code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step3:**

Create observer.php at Amit>Custommodule>Model

code is

```
 <?php
    class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Observer {
        public function myredirection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $AccountController = $observer->getEvent()->getAccountController();

        $Customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

         $response1 = Mage::app()->getResponse(); // observers have event args

            $url = 'http://www.example.com/';
            $response1->setRedirect($url);
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->sendResponse();

        return;
      }
    }
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711076/magento-1-9-redirect-customer-after-registration)

here is the logic

add this code in cart page phtml or controller

```
$myValue ='yes'; Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->setIsCart($myValue);


class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Observer {
            public function myredirection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
            $AccountController = $observer->getEvent()->getAccountController();

            $Customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

             $response1 = Mage::app()->getResponse(); // observers have event args

                $getSession =Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsCart();
              if($getSession=='yes')
               {
                $url='you checkout ur';

                 }else { $url='account url'; }
                $response1->setRedirect($url);
              Mage::app()->getFrontController()->sendResponse();

            return;
          }
        }
```

add this code in header.phtml rest the logic is explained

```
    $currentUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true));
if (strpos($currentUrl,'checkout/cart') == true || strpos($currentUrl,'checkout/onepage') == true) {
  $myValue ='yes'; 
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCurrpage($myValue);

} else {
  if (strpos($currentUrl,'customer/account/create') == true || strpos($currentUrl,'customer/account/create') == true) {

  }else {


  $myValue ='no'; 
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCurrpage($myValue); 
}}
```

update this code only

```
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Observer {
    public function myredirection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $AccountController = $observer->getEvent()->getAccountController();

    $Customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

     $response1 = Mage::app()->getResponse(); // observers have event args


        if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCurrpage()=='yes')
    {
           $url=Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage');
     } else {
     $url=Mage::getUrl('customer/account');
    }
        $response1->setRedirect($url);
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->sendResponse();

    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: how you check if the customer is in the shopping cart to redirect to the checkout else to my account? can you adapt this to work with my conditions? for login and register?

Comment: add your this logic in `$item = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
    if($item >0)
    {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }` in `$url` place

Comment: but is not good that logic, I need to check if the user visited Shopping Cart, if yes then redirect after register to the checkout page, else to the My Account

Comment: for Login the first public function is work because the Last Url is Shopping cart, but if I add the same logic in the Register then the LastUrl is not Shopping Cart Is login, because to register you will be in other page

Comment: please tell me that you understand this

Comment: @RobertD this was not mention in you question. but for that you can use magento session. the session will be created if user visit the shopping cart page if the session is there then it will redirect other wise account page then you logic work. there is no default for you logic.

Comment: I understand can you edit your answer with how I can do this?

Comment: sorry I don't understand very well you last code, how I can add that in the cart? you mean in the phtml file? or?

Comment: add in the cart  phtml file. `template/checkout/cart`

Comment: so the idea is to create the extension that you send me and add this code in cart? or just add the code in cart?

Comment: create extension but only creating session in cart page

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function setIsCart() on boolean $myValue ='yes'; Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->setIsCart($myValue);

Comment: anyway I delete that, but if I am register from homepage is redirect me to cart, if I am in the shopping cart is ok

Comment: `$myValue =array('cart'=>'yes'); Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->setIsCart($myValue);` try that.

Comment: is redirect my only to checkout, indiferent in what page I am

Comment: you want to redirect the last page you are? it redirect to cart because you visited to cart page. it only creating if you visited cart page then redirect to cart

Comment: if I am in shopping cart page I want to be redirect to checkout, in other page to my account

Comment: on login and register

Comment: it not shopping cart it is checkout page.. i think am i right.

Comment: I add a condition in the link.phtml file , if the user is not register then redirect them to the login page, All i want is when a user was in the shopping page and register or login, to be redirect after to the checkout

Comment: you want to access the checkout page after the login?

Comment: only if I am in shopping cart, if the login / register is from another page, to my account

Comment: so I need something to check if the user is or not in shopping cart page, if is in shopping cart will be redirected to login/register page and after login/register was successful redirect to checkout

Comment: you understand now what is the idea?

Comment: what is problem is using in session?

Comment: if you take a look at my login public function, I got the Last Url to check if is Shopping cart, and for login is ok, but if I want to register I need to press registration button and if I press the registration button is open the register page, so the last Url now will be Login page not Shopping Cart

Comment: ok you can set the session on other expect the login or register then it will work for you.  use this code in header or some other.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand, to use your code in header?

Comment: create session if the cart they yes other ewise set to no then riderect on that session that the logic here bro

Comment: I try a lot, but no one is work, can you make this for me please?

Comment: will be perffect if I will make this redirect in that extension. but is not so important, all i want is to have a solution, to make this to work

Comment: Hi, I add the code, is redirect me still in the My Account. I add the code exactly like here, i just copy and paste, must do something else? first code in the cart page the second code in the header

Comment: so only the code that is in header and remove that code from cart?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105561/discussion-between-robertd-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: can we talk in chat?

Comment: is the same, I add the module but is the same, you can check it if you want

Comment: hi I edit my post and I add the code that is now on my store for that redirection, take a look at very bottom at the Updated Code, the code in the header.phtml is at the top. Please tell me everything is ok? Thank you

Comment: where I need to update this code? In the observer.php?

Comment: replace it in observer.

Comment: is done but the redirection was is the My account, I made this steps: I add a product in cart, then I go in the Shopping cart, I press the Proceed to cart button, after this the redirection in the Proceed to cart button is redirect me to login page, in the login page I choose the register button, after this I was in the register page /customer/account/create/ after I press Submit, I was redirected to /customer/account/index/, what is wrong?

Comment: you check session values `echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCurrpage();` they are working correctly now debug where the problem occured.

Comment: i put this in observer but I don't see any output how we can put this to be saved in log file?

Comment: `Mage::log(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCurrpage());` this will add output in log file

Comment: perfect must be add it after if? or bellow?

Comment: Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Comment: Exception message: Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model/Observer.php, line 1

Comment: I think the method to get current page is wrong, right?

Comment: anyway the current page when you register will be always customer/account/create/ and how we can compare this? if the current page is equal checkout/cart? always will be false, and the same you can't use the LastUrl because the LastUrl in register will be always /customer/account/login/, in my first extension this I try to get the LastUrl but was not ok because the last Url in Registration page always is /customer/account/login/. The Shopping cart page is before this /customer/account/login/, and we need to check for Shopping Cart page

Comment: please tell me again, what you understand, what I need to do? I just want to know if we talk about the correct things

Comment: you want if the user come from cart page to register page then after register redirect to cart page that you want that i understand.

Comment: yes this is it, let me recap again. So I add a condition on the Proceed to Checkout button, on the ckeckout/link.pthml, this condition check if the user is login or not, if is not login then redirect to login page, all i want is after the user was redirect to the login/register page to be redirected to checkout if this redirection was in the shopping cart.

Comment: you can clearly saw the condition. read that code you will understand what you need is right there you are missing something. it is not test code so may be problem in that.

Comment: belive me I put the code on a new installation, is the same, please tell me is there any possibility to solve this?